# How to determine Big O Performance with specific examples?

Tags: java, stack

I seem to have been struggling to determine the Big O performances with these methods in my code: isEmpty(), peek(), pop(), push()ignoring resize, and size()

Would all of these methods in my ArrayStack program have a performance of Big O(1). If so, why? If not, why?

```
public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
   private E[] data;
   private int top = -1;
   private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public ArrayStack() {
      data = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
   }

   public E pop() {
      if (isEmpty()) {
         throw new EmptyStackException();
      }
      // allow garbage collection
      E save = data[top];
      data[top] = null;
      top--;
      return save;
   }

   public E peek() {
      if (isEmpty()) {
         throw new EmptyStackException();
      }
      return data[top];
   }

   public void push(E item) {
      if (data.length == size()) resize(2 * data.length);
      data[++top] = item;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return top == -1;
   }

   public int size() {
      return top + 1;
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   private void resize(int newCapacity) {
      E[] newdata = (E[]) new Object[newCapacity];
      for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
         newdata[i] = data[i];
      }
      data = newdata;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Stack<Integer> s = new ArrayStack<>();
      System.out.println("Size: " + s.size());
      for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
         s.push(i*i);
      }
      System.out.println("Size: " + s.size());
      while (!s.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.print(s.pop() + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Size: " + s.size());

      Stack<String> strings = new ArrayStack<>();
      String[] data = {"dog", "cat", "no", "geek", "computer"};
      for (String word: data) {
         strings.push(word);
      }
      while (!strings.isEmpty()) {
         System.out.print(strings.pop() + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, they are all O(1). Why? Because O(1) describes their asymptotic time complexity.

Comment: Ask yourself the following question: *Will the operation take longer if stack contained 1,000,000,000 elements?* If answer is no, then performance is _O(1)_. Only `push()` might take longer, if the backing array needs to be expanded, but overall it doesn't, exactly like the `add()` method of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), where performance is called *amortized constant time*, and is still _O(1)_.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, this makes it easier to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of work done in the methods do not change with the number of elements in the Stack nor do they change with the number of times they are called.

You can see that the work done in the methods is constant. That is exactly what is represented by **O(1)**.

On the other hand, if you consider your 'resize()', when it reaches a particular size, you are copying each element already present to a new location. So the work done is proportional to the number of elements already present. There would be more work if 1000 elements are present then if only 10 elements are present. So the runtime complexity for that call is **O(N)** where **N** is the number of elements already present in the Stack.

But if we consider amortized cost of resize, it would still be **O(1)** as in **N-1** times out of **N** it is doing constant work.